# How to drag and drop .enc file into web browser from desktop and send it to php file for processing?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I want to implement a drag and drop functionality for my webpage by which I can upload `.enc` file from desktop to webpage and send it to my PHP file for processing.

I have tried a solution which I found on the internet which does not seem to be working.

Here is the code:

```
<div id="drop_file_zone" ondrop="upload_file(event)" ondragover="return false">
        <div id="drag_upload_file">
            <p style="color:#00B3E6"><b>Drop file here</b></p>
            <input type="file" name="dragfile" id="dragfile">
        </div>
</div>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var fileobj;
    function upload_file(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    fileobj = e.dataTransfer.files[0];
    ajax_file_upload(fileobj);
    }
    function ajax_file_upload(file_obj) {
        if(file_obj != undefined) {
            var form_data = new FormData();                 
           form_data.append('dragfile', file_obj);
            $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: 'upload.php',
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: form_data,
            success:function(response) {
            alert(response);
            $('#dragfile').val('');
            }
            });
        }
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have upload.php ? That is the file which actually uploads the dragged file. It could be like this.

```
<?php
   // Edit upload location here
   $destination_path = getcwd().DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

   $result = 0;

   $target_path = $destination_path  . basename( $_FILES['dragfile']['name']);
   $actual_name = basename( $_FILES['dragfile']['name']);

   if(@move_uploaded_file($_FILES['dragfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
      $result = 1;
      echo $target_path;
   }
   else {
       echo "Error!  Could not upload file.";
   }

   sleep(1);
?>
```